# JUnitParamsRunner - cannot pass variable parameters or array of Objects to the test()?

Tags: junit

I found that I cannot declare `public void test(Obj...objects)` and use JUnitParamsRunner to parameterize my test..exception thrown at runtime.
However it works fine if I change it to `public void test(Obj obj1, Obj obj2)`
Any idea? Below is the code:

```java
private static Object[] testingParam() {
  return new Object[] { new Object[] { new Obj("123"), new Obj("123") } ];
}    

@Test
@Parameters(method = "testingParam")    
public void test(Obj...objects){
  //do some test
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't have a chance to test this, it appears [based on the usage documentation](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/test/java/junitparams/usage/Samples_of_Usage_Test.java#L56) you may need an `Obj[]` array instead of an `Object[]` array to match the vararg. Note that `Object[]` and `Obj[]` are not covariant and cannot be cast to one another.

```
private static Object[] testingParam() {
  return new Object[] { new Obj[] { new Obj("123"), new Obj("123") } };
}
```

Conversely, if you were trying to ignore the varargs and treat the parameter as a naive array, you would probably need a third array wrapper:

```
private static Object[] testingParam() {
  return new Object[] {  // <-- call the testing method once
      new Object[] {     // <-- with this array of parameters
          new Obj[] {    // <-- and the first parameter is a 2-element Obj array
              new Obj("123"), new Obj("123") } } };
}
```